Proxmox installation with Ubuntu and Windows together
I have a machine that is configured in dual boot with Linux Ubuntu and Windows 11 and I would like to know if it is possible to install Proxmox together with the two operating systems that are already installed? If possible, what is the best Grub to use in this case, could anyone help me with a tutorial, or indicating where to find materials that will help me install it?
I've already tried to find materials on this topic and haven't found anything.
